How to plot preimage of a curve by a complex polynomial
I'm trying to plot the preimage of a portion of a ray in the complex plane by a complex polynomial. Here's my code:
P[z_]=z^4-z;
RootLocusPlot[1/(P[z]+k), {k, 0, 2}, FeedbackType -> None]
a = -1+I*3^(1/2);
RootLocusPlot[1/(P[z]+k*a), {k, 0, 1}, FeedbackType -> None]

The first plot is fine, it gives me the preimage of the ray from 0 to -2, but the second one doesn't work, I get a "too small to represent a precise machine number" error and the plot is empty.
I tried to experiment with SetPrecision but that didn't work. Any help is appreciated!

Never use an upper-case letter to name a variable as it can conflict with Mathematica's internal naming conventions.

Use the option Method -> "GenericSolve"

I have no explanation why this happen for a = -1+I*3^(1/2) with exponent 1/2 but you can plot the function as the exponent approaches the limit 1/2 from both sides.
Probably some kind of singularity happens at exponent 1/2 which can be seen as crossing of yellow and green lines.
Notice that the plots are same with exponents (1/2 + 1/10^10) and (1/2 - 1/10^10) except that the colors are switched differently in that "singular" point.
P[z_] = z^4 - z;
a = -1 + I*3^(1/2 + 1/10^10);
RootLocusPlot[1/(P[z] + k*a), {k, 0, 1}, FeedbackType -> None]
a = -1 + I*3^(1/2 - 1/10^10);
RootLocusPlot[1/(P[z] + k*a), {k, 0, 1}, FeedbackType -> None]



Animation with varying exponent around 1/2.


Thank you! There is indeed a singularity, namely the polynomial has a critical value on these rays, which is what I was interested in. I guess the problem was that the green and orange curve collide at the critical point and then veer off in their own direction, and so mathematica didn't know how to differentiate them after they collide (and indeed, distinguishing them doesn't really make sense anymore)? In any case, this solves my problem, thanks!
